# Suspicious script meddling with /usr/bin/open

Tags: macos, malware, opera, malware-removal, malware-detection

I'm on macOS Ventura 13.2.1 (22D68). I run a script in my computer and the outcome was pretty much as described in [this post](https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/17066-opera-browser-appeared-in-macos-mac). So some files were installed to the `/tmp/` folder, and the Opera browser was installed. I do not know to what extend was the damage as I managed to immediately remove all files from the temporary folder, removed the Opera browser, and the ryderd daemon. I am now running an antivirus (Acronis Cyber Protect). I noticed, however, that some login items were also added to General->Login Items, and I'm particularly concerned about the `/usr/bin/open` command, which shows the message

> Item from unidentified developer.

(see image).
[image]

I believe that script changed this system file but of course I'm not sure about it (other than the message that I see). I checked on another computer running the same os and both files seem to have the same size. Of course I'm afraid that this script could lead to malware on my computer, so I'm wondering what I can do to make sure everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/open` is a part of MacOS. It's been there since at least MacOS Mojave:

```
McStudio:~ pg$ ls -l /usr/bin/open
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  105952 Jul 11  2021 /usr/bin/open*
McStudio:~ pg$ /usr/bin/open --help
open: unrecognized option `--help'
Usage: open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-s <partial SDK name>][-b <bundle identifier>] [-a <application>] [filenames] [--args arguments]
Help: Open opens files from a shell.
      By default, opens each file using the default application for that file.
      If the file is in the form of a URL, the file will be opened as a URL.
Options:
      -a                Opens with the specified application.
      -b                Opens with the specified application bundle identifier.
      -e                Opens with TextEdit.
      -t                Opens with default text editor.
      -f                Reads input from standard input and opens with TextEdit.
      -F  --fresh       Launches the app fresh, that is, without restoring windows. Saved persistent state is lost, excluding Untitled documents.
      -R, --reveal      Selects in the Finder instead of opening.
      -W, --wait-apps   Blocks until the used applications are closed (even if they were already running).
          --args        All remaining arguments are passed in argv to the application's main() function instead of opened.
      -n, --new         Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.
      -j, --hide        Launches the app hidden.
      -g, --background  Does not bring the application to the foreground.
      -h, --header      Searches header file locations for headers matching the given filenames, and opens them.
      -s                For -h, the SDK to use; if supplied, only SDKs whose names contain the argument value are searched.
                        Otherwise the highest versioned SDK in each platform is used.
```

In MacOS Ventura the application developer's "Unknown", which has confused many people. Apple forums are full of questions about it; it's often suspected to be malicious. This might be because in Ventura it appears in Login Items and runs automatically in the background, whereas in for example Mojave it does not.

Automatic run at login can be prevented in the Settings > General > Login items:

[image]

Apparently this is something most MacOS users aren't familiar with - I certainly wasn't. The new feature seems to be the autostart, which produced a popup about application from unknown developer running in the background.

Comment: I run `EtreCheck` to see what's calling `\usr\bin\open`. It turns out that there are 2 calls, one by the box.com app under User Launch Agents: `[Loaded] com.box.desktop.launch.plist (Box, Inc. - installed 2023-03-04)
    Command: /usr/bin/open -b com.box.desktop` and the other one under Launch Agents by Adobe: `[Loaded] com.adobe.ccxprocess.plist (Adobe Inc. - installed 2023-02-23)
    Command: /usr/bin/open -a '/Applications/Utilities/Adobe Creative Cloud Experience/CCXProcess/CCXProcess.app'`. The `open` command is not new though, I've been using it for opening documents since forever.

Comment: Hah! My info comes only from the postings in the Apple forums - Google search returns me about 300 of them. Dang you - I have to re-write my answer :-D